# How to check for conditional compilation symbols in csproj

Tags: c#, csproj, conditional-compilation

For security reasons, I need to exclude some code and some files from resulting `exe`. I'm using conditional compilation symbol `SECURE` for that.
Excluding code is simple

```cs
#if !SECURE
// Some secure code
#endif
```

But for files - not so much. What should I write in `Condition` below to exclude these files only if `SECURE` symbol is defined?

```cs
  <ItemGroup Condition="???">
    <Compile Remove="SecureClass.cs" />
    <None Include="SecureClass.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some digging, I found [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/issues/1438#issuecomment-370836795).

So the answer is:

```cs
  <ItemGroup Condition="$(DefineConstants.Contains('SECURE'))">
    <Compile Remove="SecureClass.cs" />
    <None Include="SecureClass.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Also tried this approach, but **it didn't work**:

```cs
<!--#if (SECURE)-->
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="SecureClass.cs" />
    <None Include="SecureClass.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
<!--#endif-->
```